# How to parse json with JSONModel with not known keys

Tags: ios, json, jsonmodel

I'm using [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/README.md#magical-data-modelling-framework-for-json) library in my iOS project, I need to manipule an object which is made of arbitrary keys and values.

I didn't find anything about this problem anywhere ... How can I manage to map unknown keys ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response I got on Github from sauvikatinnofied :

It is not possible, as the keys are unknown to JSONModel. It will be better if you declare that metadata model as NSDictionary then assess all the values using

```
for key in [metaDictionary allKeys] {
   NSLog(@"Key: %@: Value: %@", key, metaDictionary[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keys of your json data is unknown or could be anything, you should declare that model as NSDictionary, and use [BWJSONMatcher](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher) to convert your json string with data models.